# Does diagonal or vertical position affect the lifespan of a SSD drive?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I tried to find an answer for such question, but I found answers only for not of SSDs (solid-state drive). From what I know SSD disk is much different than old hard disks.

The main problem for me is too much cables inside of my PC, so I put my SSD drive in diagonal position. I'm not sure if there is a risk that disk could slide down to vertical position over time, but for sure it's not placed horizontally. Does diagonal or vertical position affect the lifespan or in any different way can affect a SSD drive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SSDs have no moving parts at all. As long as your connectors don't experience forces they weren't designed to take (wrenching them out of their sockets), you should be fine. They *can* get damaged, but thats due to catastrophic damage. Their time to failure due to old age shouldn't be affected much by orientation. With a case that crammed I'd be worried about airflow and temperatures, but that would affect your entire system, not just your SSD, and be independent of orientation.

Comment: Air flow is dependant on orientation ;)

Answer (score 1):

The mounting angle of a SSD should not have any influence on its lifespan.

(Assuming it does not slip down and blocks a fan, which would be bad for other components in your case)

Answer (score 1):

SSDs are like pendrives, nothing happens when moved

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that SSD also can work while moving them, like extreme cases as using them while you walk on street (connected to a mobile phone as external memory with tons of Videos & songs).

So position and also movement (with low G's and no impacts) does not affect them.

But after passing airport scanner, mine stated to give read and write errors (some sectors are impossible to be read again and neither write to them), so i through it to trash, no solution.

With other SSDs i have, i got weird things, like this: having SSD with Linux OS or just data, no read errors, then, after cleaning the SSD, i clone my Windows boot partition onto the SSD, then i get irrecorable read  errors, but not allways the same number of them; after cleaning the SSD and putting other type of data no read errors again.. the weird thing is that i can reproduce the weird thing.

In other words, if i put some sets of data (specific secuences of bits) it gives read errors, but no write errors and no sectors rellocated count on smart data, etc. And number of errors varies from 2 to 24 and allways if a sector has an error the next also get error (two consecutive sectors), like if all errors are of 1KiB, not 512 bytes.

It is like SSD can not hold some sort of values on some specific possitions, but that is really weird.